# What are the differences between "pass for" and "pass as"?

Tags: meaning

> These towering men could have easily passed for hardened soldiers.
>
> These towering men could have easily passed as hardened soldiers.

I was told that these two sentences basically mean the same thing. Is this the case? Also what's the difference in meaning if there's any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first sentence is the more common form, I think. But they both mean that the men could be mistaken for hardened soldiers if someone looking at them didn't know any better.